# CUDA on Windows 11 CLion new project "failed to detect a default cuda architecture"

Tags: visual-studio, cuda, clion

I have Windows 11 with Visual Studio 2022, and Cuda toolkit 11.7.99. After installing Cuda toolkit, it worked fine in Visual studio, and is also in my PATH in cmd.

However, when I try to create a new Cuda executable project in CLion, the CMake complains that `failed to detect a default cuda architecture`.

Answer (score 2):

I had to go to File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Toolchains and do both:

- change default from MinGW to Visual Studio
- Change "architecture" from x86 to amd64

After that, everything worked fine.

Not sure why it defaulted to x86, I think this is a bug in CLion or CMake; it really should be able to detect what architecture I'm using.