# CLion fails to load CUDA project: "Failed to detect a default CUDA architecture"

Tags: c++, cmake, build, cuda

I have a simple cuda project with just 2 files:

```
$ ls
CMakeLists.txt  hello.cu
```

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18 FATAL_ERROR)
project(hello LANGUAGES CUDA)
add_executable(hello hello.cu)
```

```
// hello.cu
#include <iostream>

__global__ void myKernel(void) { }

int main(void)
{
    myKernel <<<1, 1>>>();
    std::cout << "Hello CUDA world\n";
}
```

It builds successfully from terminal:

```
$ mkdir build; cd build; cmake ..; make -j4
```

But when loading with CLion, it complains about `Failed to detect a default CUDA architecture`.

Full log:

```
/home/Rahn/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch-0/223.8836.42/bin/cmake/linux/x64/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/home/Rahn/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch-0/223.8836.42/bin/ninja/linux/x64/ninja -G Ninja -S /home/Rahn/Desktop/hello-cuda-cmake -B /home/Rahn/Desktop/hello-cuda-cmake/cmake-build-debug
-- The CUDA compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at /home/Rahn/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch-0/223.8836.42/bin/cmake/linux/x64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineCUDACompiler.cmake:602 (message):
  Failed to detect a default CUDA architecture.

  

  Compiler output:

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/Rahn/Desktop/hello-cuda-cmake/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/Rahn/Desktop/hello-cuda-cmake/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

[Finished]
```

`CMakeOutput.log` and `CMakeError.log`:

```
$ cat /home/Rahn/Desktop/hello-cuda-cmake/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log
The system is: Linux - 5.10.0-21-amd64 - x86_64

$ cat /home/Rahn/Desktop/hello-cuda-cmake/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log
Checking whether the CUDA compiler is NVIDIA using "" did not match "nvcc: NVIDIA \(R\) Cuda compiler driver":
Checking whether the CUDA compiler is Clang using "" did not match "(clang version)":
Compiling the CUDA compiler identification source file "CMakeCUDACompilerId.cu" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  -v

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CUDA compiler identification source file "CMakeCUDACompilerId.cu" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  -v

The output was:
No such file or directory
```

Can someone tell me why couldn't CLion load the project?

---

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73576870/3853711) suggests to edit `File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Toolchains -> architecture` but in my case I simply couldn't those options:
[image]

Comment: The build system isn’t finding a valid compiler for the CUDA code

Comment: @talonmies But the same `CMakeLists` works fine in terminal

Comment: That may well be the case. But it doesn't change what is happening. The root cause is not finding a compiler. The error in the title of your question is only a side effect

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/cuda-projects.html#set-nvcc